# How to "flag" an index location in a 2D array?

Tags: java, eclipse, io

I am creating a Word Puzzle solver that inputs a .txt file (which is the puzzle), and outputs which words were found.

My puzzle works for some words, however if we are looking for the word "CAT" as an example in this puzzle:

```
B O B A
C D F U
E N G T
T A C H
```

As you can see, "CAT" is found the the bottom row, going left. However, my puzzle will find the first "C" in row[1] col[0] and thinks that it should start searching from there.

Is there anyway I can "flag" an index/location so that if it hits that spot and the next letter isn't an A, then it makes sure to not check that index/location again?

Thanks

Comment: Can we see your code? Sounds like an algorithm issue.

Comment: Make another 2D boolean array with the same size and simply set the value to false. But I think that you will run into trouble with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is too generic question, but for each search you can hold a list of the coordinates that you already once tried and the next time you find your letter "C" you can check in this array if you already checked a letter in this cell. If so then just continue

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do! so if the puzzle location is at puzzle[0][1] and I want to save that in a list of coordinates, how could I do so? My puzzle is a 2d char array

Comment: You have to create a separate list of coordinates and keep your failed coordinates there, then once you find your letter-candidate check its coordinates if they already exist in your coordinates list. If they do then skip this letter. If not then proceed. If you succeeded you are done. If you failed add the coordinates to your list